# Recorrer una lista de diccionarios

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

estoy tratando de hacer una agenda usando POO en Python. Aparentemente se agregan bien los contactos, el problema esta a la hora de recorrer la lista de diccionarios (contactos), me dice que no encuentra la 'key'.

```
class Agenda():

def __init__(self):
    self.contactos = [{}]

def add_contact(self):  # Añadir contacto (un diccionario)
    aux = {}
    aux["Nombre"] = input("Ingrese el nombre del contacto: ")
    aux["Telefono"] = input("Ingrese el telefono del contacto: ")
    aux["Email"] = input("Ingrese el email del contacto: ")
    self.contactos.append(aux)  # Se agrega el diccionario completo

def list_contacts(self):  # Listar contactos
    for contacto in self.contactos:  # Recorro lista
        for key in ['Nombre', "Telefono", "Email"]:
            print(f"{key}: {contacto[key]}")
```

Trate de recorrer todas las keys del diccionario porque quería imprimir una a una las claves, la verdad no se si es una mala practica o se podría hacer print(diccionario) directamente

Comment: Cambia la inicialización de `self.contactos` a `[]`. Tal como lo tienes contendría al principio un diccionario vacío que es el que te está dando problemas. Por otro lado para iterar por un diccionario puedes usar `for key in contacto`. No es buena práctica especificar "manualmente" las claves. Las sacas con un `for`. Incluso puedes sacar clave y valor directamente con `for key, value in contacto.items(): print(f'{key}: {value}')`

Answer (score 0):

Tu principal problema puede ser que `self.contactos = []` luego ya irás guardando cosas en la lista.

Tu ejercicio puede quedar algo así:

```
class Agenda:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listin = []

    def add_contacto(self):
        """Añadir Contacto"""
        contacto = {'Nombre': '', 'Telefono': '', 'Email': ''}
        for campo in contacto:
            contacto[campo] = input( f'{campo}: ')
        op = input('Cargar contacto (s/n):\t')
        if op == 's':
            self.listin.append(contacto)
            print('Contacto guardado')

    def lista_contactos(self):
        """ Lista contactos"""
        for contacto in self.listin:
            for campo in contacto:
                print(contacto[campo], end = '\t')
            print()


ag = Agenda()
for _ in range(3):
    ag.add_contacto()
ag.lista_contactos()
```

En el `__init__` simplemente creas una lista.

En la función `add_contacto` puedes crear el **diccionario** con los datos que quieres de cada **contacto**.

Puedes ir recorriéndolos con un `for`, así podrás ampliar los datos que quieres simplemente añadiéndolos al diccionario.

Para leer los datos, igual que para cargarlos, no necesitas saber los datos que hay en el diccionario:

```
for contacto in lista:
    for campo in contacto:
        print(contacto[campo]
```

Intentando hacer ese ejercicio ampliándolo un poco (tras varias versiones) me quedó algo parecido a esto:

```
@dataclass
class Agenda:
    listin: list = field(default_factory = list, init = False)
    contacto: dict = field(default_factory = dict, init = False)
    nombre: str = ''
    telef: str = ''
    email: str = ''
    nom_fich: str = 'agenda.json'

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.contacto = {'nombre': '', 'telef': '', 'email': ''}

    @staticmethod
    def __crea_menu(texto):
        titulo = '[ - - - - - - - - - - ]\n' * 2 + \
                 texto + '\n[ - - - - - - - - - - ]' * 2
        return titulo

    def add_contacto( self ):
        print(self.__crea_menu('Añadir Contacto'))
        for dato in self.contacto:
            self.contacto[dato] = input(dato + ':\t')
        print(self.contacto)

        if 's' == input('Guardar contacto (s/n)').lower():
            self.listin.append(self.contacto)

    def lista_contactos( self ):
        print(self.__crea_menu('Lista Contactos'))
        for cont in self.listin:
            for dato in cont:
                print(cont[dato], end = '\t')
            print()
        print(f'Hay {len(self.listin)} contactos')
```